# Insert a logo at the top right of a Quarto PDF file

Tags: pdf, latex, quarto

I am trying to create an academic document. I use quarto to be able to include code and formulas. How can I include my university's logo in the top left corner of my document?

For the moment here is what I have managed to do:

```
---
title: "test"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{titling}
- \pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\includegraphics[width=12cm]{nantesuniv.png}\\[\bigskipamount]}
- \posttitle{\end{center}}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
format: pdf
documentclass: report
papersize: letter
---
```

Only I can control the width and length of my logo but not its position.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the [`quarto titlepages`](https://github.com/nmfs-opensci/quarto_titlepages) extension:

```
---
title: "test"
author: "Example Author"
format: 
  titlepage-pdf:
    titlepage-logo: "nantesuniv.png"
    logo-align: left
    logo-size: 1.5
    
titlepage-theme: 
      elements: ["\\logoblock",  "\\vfill", "\\authorblock", "\\titleblock"] 
documentclass: report
papersize: letter
---
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know where I should type this code? I tried in the terminal once in VS Code but nothing happens

Comment: I have to admit that for myself, I could not get the titlepage extension even to work. So yes, some more stepwise and hands-on info would be welcome.

Comment: Have you tried to run `quarto install extension nmfs-opensci/quarto_titlepages` in the terminal?